# gzip compression is not working in azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, compression, gzip

I am using Basic plan in `azure`, but `gzip` compression is not working properly. I have tried two methods in `asp mvc` web app:

**Method 1 :** Using Action Filter

```
public class EnableCompressionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

    var encodingsAccepted = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(encodingsAccepted)) return;

    encodingsAccepted = encodingsAccepted.ToLowerInvariant();
    var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

    if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("gzip"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
        response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }
    else if (encodingsAccepted.Contains("deflate"))
    {
        response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
        response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
    }

}
}
```

**Method 2 :** Using Web.config

```
   <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />

    <httpCompression>
      <dynamicTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/x-javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8"/>
      </dynamicTypes>
      <staticTypes>
        <clear />
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="text/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="message/*"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/javascript"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/atom+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/xaml+xml"/>
        <add enabled="true" mimeType="application/json"/>
        <add enabled="false" mimeType="*/*"/>
      </staticTypes>
    </httpCompression>
```

**Request Headers in Fiddler:**

```
GET /TestAction HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**Response Headers in Fiddler:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 4.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 09 Aug 2016 13:19:34 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006236/azure-web-app-not-using-gzip-compression) post and tried to compress a simple `html` page without any scripts but still it's not working.

What could be the issue ?

Any help would be great.

Comment: Post the fiddler Request headers please

Comment: @ErikOppedijk i have added request headers, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34011032/2218697) post says  gzip compression is enabled by default for Azure Web Apps in `applicationhost.config`. but i don't see it in response headers.

Comment: The request seems ok, I once had this issue, but it was due to some company firewall in between stripping of all Accept-Encodings