# JSON compression not working on Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, gzip, http-compression

I'm working on an MVC5 web app but can't make Azure perform dynamic compression on my JsonResults. The following code in my Web.config only works when I run the web app locally, but as soon as I deploy on Azure Web App the compression does not work:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

I also tried the following, but with no luck:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
<httpCompression directory="%SystemDrive%\inetpub\temp\IIS Temporary Compressed Files">
  <scheme name="gzip" dll="%Windir%\system32\inetsrv\gzip.dll" />
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

This issue is really driving me crazy, I see no reason why this shouldn't work, considering that I found these solutions online from people who says that they implemented them successfully. Any idea?

Comment: How are you hosting it? Web App, Cloud Service, VM?

Comment: It's hosted on a Web App

Comment: Have you seen this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006236/azure-web-app-not-using-gzip-compression Looks like you'll need to edit applicationhost.config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got what the problem was: some antiviruses (including mine, which is Bitdefender) interfere with the data compression mechanism, so from my computer I couldn't see the compression happening, while in reality it was working perfectly using the following Web.config markup:

```
<urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="true" />
<httpCompression>
  <dynamicTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </dynamicTypes>
  <staticTypes>
    <add mimeType="application/json" enabled="true" />
    <add mimeType="application/json; charset=utf-8" enabled="true" />
  </staticTypes>
</httpCompression>
```

For more info about similar issues, here is an interesting article about it: https://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/11/11/whos-not-getting-gzip/